# Autosized panel which includes autosized panel shrinks to void

Tags: c#

I have 2 items `FlowLayoutPanel` each includes some buttons and has `autosize` property. Then I have a simple `Panel` docked to left. My FlowLayotPanels docked inside that panel one to top, second to bottom. I dont want to set static width to docked to left panel, but if I set `autosize` to that panel, it shrinks to zero. Somehow it doesnt "see" sizes of autosized FlowLayoutPanenls inside of it.

How to force `Panel` to see size of `FlowLayoutPanel` inside?

Comment: 'design' tag is used incorrectly. Read the tag description before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your inner panels do have content, or at least a fixed minimal size, the only thing i can imagine without some code is that you did not set the hierarch properly... You can do that by `MyParentPanel.Controls.Add(MyChildPanel1);`

Comment: Thanks, that helped =)